# CC3D OpenPilot - Communication port

Tags: raspberry-pi, quadcopter

I am building a quadrotor with a CC3D (OpenPilot) and a RPi.

My first idea is trying to communicate the CC3D with the RPi using the main port of the first one but I can't find any information about how to communicate the board with any device (or other information about the commands or serial configuration).

Anybody knows whether this is possible and where to find that info??

Comment: Which main port are you referring to? The one to rc receiver? Or the motor port? Sry for posting question here, mobile version doesnt allow me to add comment

Comment: I mean the Flexi port and the Main port. I am also trying to send PWM signals from the RPi to the CC3D using the port for the Rc Receiver, but the quadcopter doesn't move. I am not sure why.

Comment: Aaha, in arduino you cannot just use pwm to mimic rc receiver, you will need to use pulseout function instead, do you have the same for rpi?

Comment: I never used Arduino before, so I am not sure what pulseout makes at an output pint. What is the difference between make a PWM with and without using pulseout?

Comment: On stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to add  requested information, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).